# DAX measure based on two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

Based on a PERIOD dates the measure function FORECAST should choose the maximum CYCLE dates to get the quantity QTY in the PERIOD.

Example:

[image]

1. When the CYCLE_TYPE is "CURRENT" Forecats get the related QTY for the corrisponding PERIOD
2. When the CYCLE_TYPE is "OTHER" Forecast get the QTY of the maximum CYCLE date in the corrisponding PERIOD.

Comment: Given Forcast column above contains output what you want? or So far what you get? Provide the Measure code you are trying with.

Comment: Yes FORECAST is the measure I want